# Soundcloud redirect_uri_mismatch with Flask

Tags: python, oauth, flask, soundcloud, redirect

I'm developing a webapp using Python Flask. Authentication is done using Soundcloud OAuth. 
I developed everything locally and it worked fine. 
I configured the Soundcloud app 'Redirect URI' to

```
http://localhost:5000/index
```

Then I wanted to deploy the app on a Digital Ocean virtual root server using Ubuntu 14.04 (as used for development). 
And from then whichever 'Redirect URI' I provided it didn't work. 
I used:

- http://178.62.???.??:5000/index
- http://178.62.???.??/index

Gives me:

http://178.62.???.???:5000/index?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirection+URI+provided+does+not+match+a+pre-registered+value.#

I have no clue how to get that running.

Anyone used Soundcloud OAuth with Flask and got it running?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570311/bug-soundcloud-oauth2-connection-will-fail-if-redirect-uri-includes-charac

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I forgot to change the redirect_uri when building the client object. It was still set to localhost. Phew...

Comment: doohhh.. :) that happens..